# 1998 Accord headlight

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, headlight

I have a 1998 Honda Accord.  The driver's side high and low beam work but passenger side high and low beam does not work. I swapped out relays and checked the fuses no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the socket connections for voltage.

If you have voltage at the socket, you could swap bulbs to verify - but if the filaments are broken, you just need a new bulb.